# Bin Icon is Gone From the Panel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, there was previously a trash image (icon) in the panel section. When I clicked on it the terminal was clearing. But it no longer exists. I changed accidently panel settings. For solving, I clearing settings.json folder but still same. Why does it never revert back to its old settings?

Comment: Because `Terminal Tabs` `enabled` is the new default.  I think the only way to get the bin back is to disable `Terminal Tabs`.

Answer (score 0):

---

### The Trash-bin Icon is Still Very Much Present in Your Editor

---

> "The other solutions here, though no wrong in what they say, are not good solutions. The icon is still present if you know where to look, and you didn't accidentally change your settings. In the last VSCode update — ["the May-2021 Update (v1.57.1)"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_terminal-tabs) — the VS-Code team added support for the new feature, **"Terminal Tabs"**, which does more than add *terminal-tabs*, it offers users an entire new UI to use. It also switched the configurations of millions of unexpected VSCode users, so that the new UI was auto-equipped. In all fairness you are not the first person to wonder where the *"Trash-bin Icon"* went. I answered another question, 2 weeks ago, asking about the drop-down that is no longer visible."

### You have two options available to you.

---

1. ###### You can, keep the new UI the way it is, and below is a picture that shows where the new terminal tab trash-bin icon is.
2. ###### Or you can switch back to the old UI using the setting bellow:

###### `terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled: (true/false)`

---

###### Image shows `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false`, and where the trash icon is. It is important to note that the icon auto hides, and one must scroll over it before it reveals itself.

---

[image: Terminal-Tabs Enabled]

---

###### Image shows `"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true`, and where the trash icon is located using the old UI. I think its fair to note, the new UI was created to make VSCode better. People use to download extensions to get the same terminal tabs that the new UI offers.

---

[image: Terminal-Tabs Disabled]